# Hibernate - Rollback list of entities if one entity fails

Tags: java, hibernate

im just working on a project to create, change user in my mysql database. Therefore i have UserService (REST) which creates a user and a GenericDAO class where i can persist users. In my DAO for each user i begin, persist and commit a transaction. Creating single users or find users works perfect.

Now i am facing with the problem to persist or update a list of users. Especially if one user can not be persisted (e.g. duplicates) the hole transaction should be rolled back. It doesnt work in my current setup.

My first idea is to outsource the commit in a separate method. With an loop over all users i only persist them. At the end of the loop i would call my method to commit everything. If a single or more users fails i can catch them with the rollback. Is that a good approach?

AbstractDAO (current)

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<T> implements IGenericDAO<T>{

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em = null;
    private CriteriaBuilder cb = null;
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public GenericDAO(Class<T> class1) {
        this.clazz = class1;
        this.em = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();
        this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    }
    
    public final void setClazz(Class<T> clazzToSet) {
        this.clazz = clazzToSet;
    }

    public T create(T entity) {
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(entity);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return entity;
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public T find(int id) {
        return em.find(this.clazz, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return em.createQuery("from "+this.clazz.getName()).getResultList();
    }

    /** Save changes made to a persistent object. */
    public void update(T entity) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.merge(entity);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    /** Remove an object from persistent storage in the database */
    public void delete(T entity) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(entity);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Comment: There's no point in catching a `PersistenceException` and *then* rollbacking, a `PersistenceException` will cause a rollback automatically

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the most convenient solution be to simply add methods like `createAll()/updateAll()`?

Adding separate public methods for starting and persisting the transaction like `start()` and `commit()` creates a whole bunch of problems because it means you suddenly introduce a *stateful conversation* between the `Dao` and its clients.

The `Dao` methods now need to be called in a certain order and, worse still, the state of the `EntityManager` transaction is retained. If you forget to `commit()` at the end of one service call using your `Dao`, a subsequent call is going to mistakenly assume a transaction was not yet started, and that call is going to fail 'for no apparent reason' (not to mention that the original call will appear completed when in reality the transaction was left hanging). This creates bugs that are hard to debug, and tricky to recover from.

EDIT As I already pointed out in the comment below this answer, getting programmatic transaction management right is tricky in a multi-layer application structure, and so, I would recommend to have a look at declarative transaction management.

However, **if you insist** on managing transactions yourself, I would probably introduce sth like a `TransactionTemplate`:

```
public class TransactionTemplate {
   
    private EntityManager em; //populated in a constructor, for instance

    public void executeInTransaction(Runnable action) {
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            action.run();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            em.clear(); // since you're using extended persistence context, you might want this line
        }
    }

}
```

and use it in a service like so:

```
public class UserService {

    private TransactionTemplate template;
    private RoleDao roleDao;
    private UserDao userDao; //make sure TransactionTemplate and all Daos use the same EntityManager - for a single transaction, at least

    public void saveUsers(Collection<User> users, String roleName) {
        template.executeInTransaction(() -> {
            Role role = roleDao.findByName(roleName);
            users.forEach(user -> {
                user.addRole(role);
                userDao.create(user);
            });
            // some other operations
        });
    }

}
```

(of course, using the above approach means only one layer - the service layer in this case - is aware of transactions, and so DAOs must always be called from inside a service)

Comment: Hey, adding the createAll should be done in my DAO, right? I also played with this idea. It would beans if i use this method i have to explicit open the connection one and of course closing at the end (via catch of is connection is close open it). I will have multiple services and daos. If one of the services/daos doesnt handle it right i would have a never ending transaction why i would avoid that way.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understood your comment, but if you have multiple services using multiple daos, getting programmatic transaction management right is tricky. I would recommend to look at ways to handle transactions declaratively (using a framework like Spring, or even a more lightweight solution like [Guice with Guice Persist](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JPA))

Comment: Also, if you insist on handling transactions yourself, see my updated answer

Comment: I have tried to take over the declarative transaction management. I try to store three entities with my REST service, the last one must cause a roll-back. Unfortunately the first two are persisted directly into the DB and cannot undo the complete transaction. Could it be that i have to pass the entitymanager to my DAO?

Comment: It is difficult to answer without looking at the code and knowing what library/framework you've ended up using, but if you suspect a `RESOURCE_LOCAL` transaction is not properly started, you can debug the issue by checking the value of `entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()`. Most of the frameworks have a way of inspecting the current transaction state, in Spring, you can check the `TransationSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()`, for instance

Comment: Changed to JTA instead of resource_locale. Had more issues with the resource_local transcation type (https://github.com/ViFire/docCore-backend). I guess my main problem is the placement of the entitymanager from the service and the dao.